# How to check my NSString is exist in my NSMutableOrderedSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, twilio-programmable-chat, nsmutableorderedset

I am getting below response from the one of the third party SDK, Now how to check that my String  value is exist in the response? And the key I need to compare with `friendlyName` key.

```
 channelList = (
     "<<TCHChannel: 0x2816df040>: sid: 'CH84', friendlyName: 'Mihir : MihirOza', attributes: '(null)'>",

     "<<TCHChannel: 0x2816dc480>: sid: '644d', friendlyName: 'Testchannel2', attributes: '(null)'>",

     "<<TCHChannel: 0x2816dff40>: sid: 'df38', friendlyName: 'privateios', attributes: '(null)'>" )
```

Here is the code which I am using.

```
TCHChannels *channelsList = [[[ChatManager sharedManager] client] channelsList];
NSMutableOrderedSet<TCHChannel *> *newChannels = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init];
[newChannels addObjectsFromArray:[channelsList subscribedChannels]];
NSMutableArray<TCHChannel *> *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[newChannels array]];
NSLog(@"channelList = %@",temp);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check my answer, If it solves your issue then please mark it as approved so it will be helpful to others who have the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
NSPredicate *Pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"TCHChannel.friendlyName == 'yourstring'"];
NSArray *arr = [temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Comment: It's getting crash `reason: '[<TCHChannel 0x280aa7f80> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TCHChannel.'`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
NSMutableArray<TCHChannel *> *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[newChannels array]];
NSLog(@"channelList = %@",temp);

NSPredicate *Pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"friendlyName == 'yourMatchString'"];
NSArray *arr = [temp filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```